# Using XeLaTeX in place of LaTeX to format labels in an interactive window

Tags: matplotlib, pdflatex, xelatex

This Python code gives an error

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
matplotlib.pyplot.text(0,0,'π')
```

The stack trace (loongish, for now omitted) informs me that the external command that has lead to the failure is

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error /home/.../.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/....tex
```

and on my Debian system `latex` is indeed `pdflatex`.  To get what I want I should be able to invoke `xelatex`, but afaik there is no configuration item that tells Matplotlib to do that…

What can I do to have Matplotlib invoke `xelatex` instead of `latex` aka `pdflatex` ?

---

***Notes***:

1. I'd prefer to avoid patching
   `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py`.
2. I know that I can use the `inputenc` package to do what is in my example, but it's just an example and I really want to do something else using `xelatex`.
3. I want to use an interactive back end.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/pgf.html

Comment: @tmdavison Oops, I made an edit to my question: I want to use an interactive back end.   Sorry for the misleading way in which I originally asked.  If it is possible to use the `pgf` back end to format labels etc in an interactive window, I'd like to know the how to because I wasn't able to have it working.